# Using badblocks with mkfs -l

Tags: badblocks, mkfs

`mkfs.vfat -c` does a simple check for badblocks.`badblocks` runs multiple passes with different patterns and thus detects intermittent errors that `mkfs.vfat -c` will not catch.

`mkfs.vfat -l filename` can read a file with badblocks from `badblocks`. But  I have been unable to find an example on how to generate the file using badblocks.

My guess is that it is as simple as:

```
badblocks -w /dev/sde1 > filename
mkfs.vfat -l filename /dev/sde1
```

But I have been unable to confirm this. Is there an authoritative source that can confirm this or explain how to use `badblocks` to generate input for `mkfs.vfat -l filename`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man badblocks`:

```
   -o output_file
          Write the list of bad blocks to  the  specified  file.   Without
          this option, badblocks displays the list on its standard output.
          The format of this file is suitable for use by the -l option  in
          e2fsck(8) or mke2fs(8).
```

So the correct way would be:

```
badblocks -o filename /dev/sde1
mkfs.vfat -l filename /dev/sde1
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but you have to pass block size to badblocks in order to match properly with filesystem block size. for ext4 I run `mkfs.ext4 -c /dev/sde1` and it runs for me `badblocks -b 4096 -X -s /dev/sde1`.